# Big Query - Formatting Dates

Tags: sql, string, date, google-bigquery

I have two date fields in separate tables but need to reformat one of them in order to join on the fields. I am using standard SQL in Big Query.

The first table has the date format I'd like to continue using - it is formatted as a date and is in these terms, "2020-06-19" so YYYY-MM-DD.

The second table that has the date field I need to update is currently a string and the date is in the following format: "9/1/20" so MM/DD/YY.

Any suggestions on how I can cast the second date field as a date and in the YYYY-MM-DD format so that I can join these two tables?

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `parse_date()` to turn the string in the second table to a date:

```
parse_date('%m-%d-%y', mycol)
```

You can then use that `date` to join the other table.

As an alternative, we can use `%D`, which stands for  `%m/%d/%y`:

```
parse_date('%D', replace(mycol, '-', '/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use below

```
parse_date('%m/%d/%y', date_as_string)
```

when applied to string `9/1/20` - it returns `2020-09-01` as a date data type

so, your join condition will looks like

```
on date_as_date = parse_date('%m/%d/%y', date_as_string)
```